# Database Schema Update - Users with multiple Companies

Tags: mysql, sql

My team initially developed an application for a specific Client where the main goal is for their employees to register their work by inserting tasks for the projects they are assigned to. All information is related to the Users (the Tasks table have a Created_By field which is a User relation).

Now the requisites changed and we need to change the application and make it capable of working with multiple Clients (let's call them Companies) in the same instance. A User must be capable of belonging to multiple Companies.

Almost all information about a User is company dependent, except his name, his email and his credentials. We changed the structure and have the tables user, company, and company_user.
The company_user holds the relation between the User and a company as well as user company dependent data, like his jobTitle or jobLevel.

Currently the other tables have relations with User, but because almost all information needed is in the company_user table, should I change that relation to be with company_user instead of User? This is what i have now:

```
USER
id
name
company_id

TASK
id
name
user_id
```

Now I want multiple companies for the user, so I changed it to

```
USER
id
name

USER_COMPANY
id
user_id
company_id

TASK
id
name
user_id
```

The question is, should I change the TASK table to

```
TASK
id
name
user_company_id
```

or leave the it like I have now?

```
TASK
id
name
user_id
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can a `user` perform the same `task` for different `companies`?

Comment: no. The task has a company_id too. Everything an User does is for a specific company.

Comment: If the task already has a `company_id` (which makes sense), it can have just a `user_id` to link it to a `user`.

Comment: If `TASK` already connects `USER` with `COMPANY`, why do you need `USER_COMPANY` all?

Comment: i know, but everytime i need to show a task, or anything from other table that is related to an User, i need to show information from the table company_user, such as the user jobTitle on that company. And with the fields company_id and user_id, i always need to perform an extra query to get that information from the table company_user. Thats my question, should i maintain the structure i have or replace user_id with company_user_id.